# If $Q$ is a Sylow $q$ subgroup of $S_q$ with $q$ prime, prove that $C_{S_q}(Q) = Q$

Tags: group-theory

Here is what I have so far:

We know that $Q$ must have order $q$ since $q$ is prime. Because the order of a subgroup of $S_q$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of all disjoint cycles in the subgroup. If there were an element in $Q$ that is composed of two disjoint nontrivial cycles of order $m$ and $n$ then the order of that element, which is l.c.m. of $m$ and $n$, must divide the order of $Q, q$. But this is impossible since $q$ is prime and $m$ and $n$ are greater than $1$. Hence all elements of $Q$ are $q$-cycles. Pick one element in it, say $\sigma$. Then $ < \sigma >$ is a subgroup of $Q$ which is itself order $q$ hence $Q$ itself. As $Q$ is thus shown to be cyclic, $Q \leq C_{S_q}(Q)$. Now we must show the other direction.

We know that two elements of $S_q$ are conjugates iff they are of same cycle order. We also know that if $\tau, \sigma = (a_1,...,a_m) \in S_q$ then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1),...,\tau(a_m))$ (and in fact this is used to prove the former statement).

So, if $\tau \in C_{S_q}(Q)$ and $\sigma = (b_1,...,b_q) \in Q$ then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(b_1),...,\tau(b_q)) = (b_1,...,b_q)$ and thus $\tau = id$. Hence $\tau \in Q$.

Here is my problem: the reasoning in last paragraph shows that $C_{S_q}(Q)$ is $1$, which is not true since it must contain a subgroup of order $q > 1$.

What's the problem with my proof above? Any other helpful comments are appreciated.

Edit: I realize that my mistake must be the statement "$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(b_1),...,\tau(b_q)) = (b_1,...,b_q) \implies \tau = id$", since $(b_1,...,b_q) = (b_j,...,b_{j+q})$ with the notation $b_i = b_{i+q}$ for all $i$. But I am atill having trouble correcting $\tau$ must be in $Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your edit, you should note that you have shown $|C_{S_q}(Q)|\le q$, since there are $q$ choices of which letter to start with when you write down a $q$-cycle, and you have at most one $\tau$ corresponding to each of those choices.  Since you also know $Q\le C_{S_q}(Q)$ and $|Q|=q$, you can conclude $Q=C_{S_q}(Q)$, since the centralizer can't be any larger.

In other words, you've already done the hard part of the proof.  Congratulations!

Per your request, here's a simpler way: Let $x$ be a generator of $Q$.  If any element $z$ of $C_{S_q}(Q)$ has order divisible by a prime other than $q$ (say by $r$), then some power of $z$ (call it $y$) has order $r$ and thus $xy$ has order $qr$, which is impossible, since there is not room with only $q$ letters to have a disjoint $q$-cycle and $r$-cycle, which is needed to get an element of order $qr$.  Therefore, $C_{S_q}(Q)$ must be a $q$-group.  But since $q^2$ does not divide $|S_q|$, this means $|C_{S_q}(Q)|\le q$ and thus $C_{S_q}(Q)=Q$.

Comment: Thanks, I selected your answer. Do you know any easier way to prove my claim? My book (Dummit and Foote 3rd edition, page 143 referring to Example 2 Section 3) refers to a short explanation which I cannot understand. If you could read and explain that'd be great

Comment: I don't have Dummit and Foote available, but I added a simpler proof above.